# Why and when would workflow engine cancel a long running site workflow in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I had an infinite site workflow running in SharePoint Online and processing subwebs. It was supposed to run and then pause for 12 hours. I just found that the workflow stopped running a while ago, and there was no workflow instance available, so I couldn't see what exactly happened to it - was it terminated, canceled, errored? However, the workflow history still contained all the loggs, and I could see that the workflow run successfully for 114 days and then suddenly stopped. 114 days doesn't really make any sense to me.

We know that in SharePoint Online, the Workflow Auto Cleanup job permanently deletes workflow instances 60 days after a workflow is completed or canceled. My workflow wasn't completed but had no instances, so the question is, what and why canceled my workflow after 114 days? If a workflow had an error, would it be canceled after a certain period? If so, what period would that be and how can we be notified about it?